# Semilinear heat equation - references

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

This is a reference request - could someone recommend a book about semilinear heat equation / reaction diffusion equations ? Highly valuable if it contains systems of these equations too. 
Mainly, I am interested in solvability (classical sense, but also strong solutions).
I have been reading Friedman's PDE of parabolic type, but seems it's not enough for my purposes.
Thanks!

Comment: This might be a long shot but you could check on Lieberman.